# Compare values in one column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame in Pyspark.I would like to check the column (B) if there is null value and if the previous value before the null is non-null value then count the number of nulls and store it in a new column (c). Then if I reach new value then reset the count and start a new count.Actually, it is time series data and we want to know the gap size.

```
B      C
---------
1      0
--------
null   1
--------
null   2
--------
null   3
--------
3      0
--------
7      0
---------
null   1
---------
null   2
----------
```

Comment: It's customary on Stack Overflow to provide at least *some* code to show that you've attempted this yourself.

Comment: it solved by trick